# changing permissions on certain categories

Tags: members, ifelse, permissions

I have a page that hides some amount of page content for free viewers. We have a certain category of 'sample' articles which should be available for everyone. Is there an if clause which basically reads if category = x show all content regardless of membership member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly, but you could put your Channel Entries tag into an embedded template, and use a member group ID conditional to send it the parameters you want based on the visitors membership status.

```
{if logged_in_group_id == 7}
    {embed="template_group/_template_name" categories="1|2|3|4"}
{if:else}
    {embed="template_group/_template_name" categories="1"}
{/if}
```

And on the `template_group/_template_name` embedded template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" category="{embed:categories}"}
```